# How to put 3D Maya animation on iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, 3d, maya

We are trying to do a 3D startup animation in Maya.

Whats the best way to put that animation into iOS Xcode ?

For example, there is www.coreanimator.com but this is for 3D. Anything i can do to ensure 3D animation is imported well (and optimized) into Xcode ios app ? Any suggestion would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you should start reading UnityGameEnigine. Unity has everything you require. Here is the URL for [Unity](https://unity3d.com/)

Comment: this is not a game and unity is a game engine. its just an app that wish to include 3D animations.

Comment: Unity is a game engine but you can also develop app with that. It's just a tool so you can develop anything it supports

Comment: Great. Someone asked you a specific question and you reply "use other software". How does this help the OP?